# Deleting a node at a given index in Java; What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have been stuck for the last 40-so minutes on this problem. I'm unsure of what I am doing wrong here, I have tried debugging many times and have read similar Q/A's. Can't figure it out and my assignment is due at midnight.

It is not deleting the Node.. None at all in fact. If the code seems right, then the problem may be lying inside main. Let me know, please & thank you!

Any help is well appreciated! :)

**Problem Method Below**

```java
void deleteAtIndex(int idx) 
    {
    if (length() >= idx)
    {
        if(idx == 0)
        {
            head = head.getNext();
        }
        else
        {
            Node temp = findAtIndex(idx-1);
            temp.setNext(temp.getNext().getNext());
        }
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid position");
    }
```

**Full Class Code Below**

```
public class ShapeLinkedList {
public Node head; // Head is first node in linked list
public ShapeLinkedList() { }
public ShapeLinkedList(Node head) {
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return length() == 0;
}
public void insertAtEnd(Shape data) {
Node end = new Node(data, null);
    if (head == null)
        head.setNext(end);
    else
        tail().setNext(end);
}
public void insertAtBeginning(Shape data) {
    if (data != null)
    {
        Node temp = new Node(data, head);
        head = temp;
    }
}
public Node tail() {
if (head == null){
    return null;
}
else
{
    Node temp = head;
    while(temp.getNext() != null){
        temp = temp.getNext();
    }
    return temp;
}
}
public int length() { // 1
    Node temp = head;

    if (temp == null)
        return 0;

    int tempIndex = 0;
    while(temp.getNext() != null){
        temp = temp.getNext();
        tempIndex++;
    }
    return tempIndex;
}
void insertAtIndex(int idx, Shape data) { //3
    if (length() >= idx)
    {
        Node current = new Node(data, null);
        Node temp = findAtIndex(idx);

        current.setNext(temp.getNext());
        temp.setNext(current);
    }
}
Node findAtIndex(int idx) { // 2
    if (length() >= idx)
    {
        Node temp = head;
        for(int i = 0; i < idx; i++)
        {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        return temp;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
void deleteAtIndex(int idx) { //4
    if (length() >= idx)
    {
        if(idx == 0)
        {
            head = head.getNext();
        }
        else
        {
            Node temp = findAtIndex(idx-1);
            temp.setNext(temp.getNext().getNext());
        }
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid position");
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "";
}
void deleteData(Shape s) {
    Node temp = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < length(); i++)
    {
        if(temp.getData() == s)
            deleteAtIndex(i);
    }
}
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return false;
}
// Node is nested class because it only exists along with linked list
public static class Node {
    private Shape data;
    private Node next;

    public Node(Shape S, Node N){
        data = S;
        next = N;
    }

    public Node getNext(){
        return next;
    }
    public Shape getData() { return data; }
    public void setNext(Node N) { next = N; }
// TODO develop all the methods that are needed
// such as constructors, setters, getters
// toString, equals, hashCode
}
}
```

Comment: midnight was 3 hours ago ;-)

Comment: 3 hours ago for youuu :P 
9:15pm here :\

Comment: You see, all about context ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple bugs in your class. I guess if you fix them, your code will work fine. SO is not a debugging platform, thus your question is off-topic and you should learn using a debugger.

Here some issues I instantly have seen from a quick look at your code, I'm sure there are more issues:

- `if (length() >= idx)` should probably be `if (length() > idx)` at all places and
- `if (head == null) head.setNext(end);` should probably be `if (head == null) head = end;` and
- `public ShapeLinkedList(Node head) { }` should probably be `public ShapeLinkedList(Node head) { this.head = head; }` and
- `int tempIndex = 0` should probably be `int tempIndex = 1`

Comment: Ohh man. I got it. It was freaking working all that time. It was in my main method >_<